# Replace repetitive html php only images & text change

Tags: php, html, css

My portfolio website has been functioning fine for some years, but I'm looking to optimise a lot of repetitive HTML. It's becoming a huge list (up to 150 images on lazyload). I assume I should be using PHP but my knowledge is minimal and don't know where to start (have searched a lot).
I'm using Atom.

This is the link to what it is now: http://www.daynacasey.com/

I have many sections in which I have text + thumbnails that hover with CSS.
Things I would like to optimise:
– Is there a way to generate the "imagetotal" divs? The only things that change are the image titles. If so, how to call each image?
– I repeat the thumbnail and hover image as the same, is there a way to call 'same image'? I'd rather preload the hover than have a smaller thumbnail.
– Are there ways to generate alttext? Within sections there is similar text.

```
    <section id="#one" class="project sections">
    <div class="text">
    Lorum ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="leftimages">

       <div class="imagetotal">
          <img src="placholder.jpg" data-original="/imgs/ONE/image.jpg" class="hover lazy" alt="alttext"/>
          <div class="enlarge enlargehover">
          <img data-original="/imgs/ONE/image.jpg" alt="alttext" >
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="imagetotal">
          <img src="placholder.jpg" data-original="/imgs/ONE/image2.jpg" class="hover lazy" alt="alttext"/>
          <div class="enlarge enlargehover">
          <img data-original="/imgs/ONE/image2.jpg" alt="alttext" >
          </div>
       </div>

    </div>  
    </section>
```

CSS

```
    .leftimage img {max-height: 100%; width: auto; max-width: 100%; height: auto;}

    .enlargehover{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 300px;
    display: none;
    margin:  1vw 3%;
    height: 98%;
    z-index: 8;
    } 

    .imagetotal a {display: block!important;}
    .imagetotal:hover .enlarge {display: block!important;}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You do not even need PHP. You can do this using a Handlebars template. Or just create a hidden section with the appropriate tags, then clone it, replace the changing parts, and append the newly created section, display visible, in the appropriate points of the DOM. Since you will do this in a loop, establish a counter, and add it to the corresponding hidden div's ids, so that you have thumb37, image37, div73 and so on, and they are unique.

Comment: You can do by javascript...you have to set all images in a javascript array..and do ` for loop`  to do the repeatative html divs..

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm diving into these suggestions to see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 comes with the `<template>` element. A small example should explain the usage together with the help of native javascript.

```
<section id="one">

</section>
<template id="imagetotal">
    <div class="imagetotal">
        <img src="" data-original="" class="hover lazy" alt="">
        <div class="enlarge enlargehover">
            <img data-original="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    // array with your image data
    var data = [
        {
            src : 'placeholder.jpg',
            data : '/imgs/ONE/image.jpg',
            alt : 'bla',
        }
    ];
    if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {

        // get all needed dom elements
        var section = document.getElementById('one'),
            template = document.getElementById('imagetotal'),
            img = template.querySelector('div.imagetotal > img'),
            enlargeimg = template.querySelector('div.enlarge > img');

        data.forEach(function(element) {
            // set template data
            img.src = element.src;
            img.dataset.original = element.data;
            img.alt = element.alt;

            enlargeimg.dataset.original = element.data;
            enlargeimg.alt = element.alt;

            // clone the template content and append it to the dom
            let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            section.appendChild(clone);
        });
    }
</script>
```

For detailed information about the HTML5 element have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template. The template element is widely supported by [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template). For Internet Explorer 11 there are good polyfills, so the template tag can be used for this old browser.